# Can't extract ubuntu-mate .xz

Tags: pi-2, ubuntu

I downloaded Ubuntu mate from [Ubuntu-Mate Website](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz) . I am unable to extract the .xz file in my mac. On extracting file, it generates .cpgz file.

Please help me to extract the .img file and boot on a memory card.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To unpack run `gunzip fullpath.xz`

**NOTE** this deletes the `xz` file; use `-k` if you want to keep it.

Incidentally `shasum -a 256 fullpath.xz`will let you check the file checksum.